# How to use jQuery conditional statement and event handling to make an element fade out and fade in depending on browser width?

Tags: jquery, browser, event-handling, resize, fadein

I want to check the browser width, and if it's more than 850, to fade in a div.

Then whenever the browser is resized, I want to fade out that div if the browser width is less than 850, and fade it in again if the browser width is more than 850.

Thank you in advance for helping out with this!

Dimitri Vorontzov

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use the `$(window).width()` [(doc)](http://api.jquery.com/width/) to get the browser's width. Use the `resize` event to handle the changes in browser size. [(doc)](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

> The resize event is sent to the window element when the size of the browser window changes:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 850) {
         // do something 
    } else {
         // do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Konstant, your advise was very helpful.